# Cordova deviceReady not called on Android platform

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am trying to build a simple cordova app on iOS and Android. It worked fine on iOS. However it fails to execute on android. I am using Android Studio.

The html file still runs in android, but the addEventListener for deviceReady is not working.

This piece of code works fine in iOS but not in android:

```
        <p id="ready" style="text-align: center">deviceready not called yet</p>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {

                                      console.log("cordova ready");
                                      var readyElement = document.getElementById("ready");
                                      readyElement.innerHTML = "deviceready called but not finished";
                                      readyElement.innerHTML = "Ready";
                                      console.log('Ready');
                                      }, false);
            </script>
```

I have included the both cordova-2.4.0.js and cordova.js in the project folder, but I have no idea why it doesnt connect properly.

After the page loads, the label 'device ready not called yet should be changed to device ready' , but it doesnt change in android. Can anyone suggest me the right way to do it ?

**Note**: 'cordova.js' is generated by the cordova in android , and 'cordova-2.4.0.js' is the one generated in iOS.
Even though I copied the iOS cordova-2.4.0.js file, it didnt worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have to include only one cordova.js file generated by the cordova .

I removed the line:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
```

and I used only:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

and it worked.